# Python Selenium - How to Click AJAX Button? (Selenium not finding XPath)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

**In Python Selenium, how can I click an AJAX button using XPath?**

Example:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="btn_fx_contract"]').click
```

This button is Zebra_Dialog.

The HTML is:

```
<input type="button" id="btn_fx_contract" class="btn_fx_print_red" value="accept" onclick="fx_contract_save('0000000', 'B')">
```

The function `fx_contract_save` is AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element_by_id('btn_fx_contract').click
```

Searching by id is a way more reliable way

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML to click on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- *CSS-SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.btn_fx_print_red#btn_fx_contract"))).click()
  ```
- *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='btn_fx_print_red' and @id='btn_fx_contract']"))).click()
  ```